# Android gallery get image name

Tags: android, android-layout

In the below code i have created a gallery object and also have included a image view,on click of image how to get the image name and load it in image view.I have also included main.xml

```
package HelloGallery.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloGalleryActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    final ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGalleryActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             iv.setsource("android:src="@drawable/"+imagename); //how to do this



        }
    });

}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2,
            R.drawable.sample_3

    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return i;
    }

/*  public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }*/
}
}
```

Main.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
 <TextView  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="@string/hello"
 />
 <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/gallery"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
iv.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: Will R.drawable.icon give me the icon name?

Comment: no it will return the drawable obj corressponding to R.id.icon

Comment: But some how i see that the default android image is being loaded..What could be wrong